# Where can I find W. Browder's thesis

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homology, loop-spaces

I've been looking for W. Browder's thesis *Homology of loop spaces* for a while now, and I really found nothing except for articles and book having it in their bibliography. Does someone know if it can be found somewhere on the internet, whether it is for free or not ?

Comment: Have you tried browder@math.princeton.edu?

Comment: only two libraries seem to have it: https://www.worldcat.org/title/homology-of-loop-spaces/oclc/32878642?referer=br&ht=edition

Comment: As a start, Browder's paper "Homology operations and loop spaces" was published in Illinois J. Math. 4 1960 347–357. In [this copy on Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255456051) you can find the following "I would like to express my warm appreciation to Professor J. C. Moore. This paper is part of a dissertation written under his direction, presented to Princeton University."

Comment: If you have a university affiliation you should be able to get it from Princeton by interlibrary loan.

Comment: ProQuest has an entry for it, but no digital copy: https://www.proquest.com/docview/301883871/5885E7EC5324BB6PQ/6?accountid=10474&sourcetype=Dissertations%20&%20Theses Did you ever find one?